# Do custom permissions stops Google Play from auto-update?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

**Scenario:**

I have an app already deployed on Google Play.

For some internal reasons, we'll have a separate app (separate .apk) which define a custom permission on the manifest:

```
<permission
   android:name="<my.app.package>.PERMISSION.extras"
   android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

and the **existing** app will use this permission.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="<my.app.package>.PERMISSION.extras"/>
```

both apps are signed with our key and it the communication between the two apks is working fine.

**Now the question:**

because of this new custom permission, will Google Play:

- require our users to go to `Google Store -> My Apps -> <my.app> -> Update`

or

- just auto-update as usual, and it only cares about the new permissions if it is one of the `android.permission.*` permissions ?

Any well based information will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question I setup a small test.

test procedure:

- created new google account, on a tablet and downloaded the app
- added this new user to the G+ community for Alpha testers of the app.
- on this user account, accepted to be an alpha tester
- double checked that the app is with `auto-update` enabled.
- pushed an update to the app with the new custom permission.
- await for the cloud...

results:

- on Google play developer console it shown the extra permission on both the total number of permissions and the list of permissions.
- after a few hours the tablet auto-updated with no problems.
- the custom permission are not shown on Google Play Store in the tablet
- the custom permission are not shown on the tablet Settings -> Apps -> My App -> Permissions

**so final answer:**

custom permissions with signature level protection do not stop the `auto-update` from Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

I believe custom permissions would fall under the category of "Other." Based off [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en), you'll be asked to download the update when adding the permission. If the permission has already been approved, this may be different.

Whether or not the user has to manually go to the Play Store to get updates or if the app updates itself is also a different matter. This is dependent on the user settings within their Play Store application. You can refer to "App Updates" in the page linked previously. With Auto-Update enabled the user won't be prompted to approve permissions if the new permission group has been previously added (this may not apply in your case because it's a custom permission). **No matter what**, if your app is adding a new permission group, the user will be asked to accept the update.

I believe only if the user has auto updates disabled and notifications disabled for their Play Store application, will they need to manually go to the Play Store -> App -> Update.